# React Fetch Returning Unusable __proto__ objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to get to the `special_abilities` array at the following api endpoint: http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters/1

Here is my container component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import MonsterSpecialAbilities from '../components/MonsterSpecialAbilities'

class MonstersContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      monster: {},
      number: Math.floor((Math.random())*325)
    }
    this.handleRandomClick = this.handleRandomClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters/${this.state.number}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        this.setState({ monster: responseData })
      })
  }

  render() {
    let spec_abilities;
    spec_abilities = this.state.monster.special_abilities.map((ab) => {
      return(
        <MonsterSpecialAbilities
          desc={ab.desc}
        />
      )
    })
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.monster.name}
        {spec_abilities}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MonstersContainer
```

Right now the `.map` function breaks my components, and I get the console error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.monster.special_abilities.map is not a function`. I tried accessing the array by trying to access `this.state.monster.special_abilities[0]`, but this returns as `null`, leading me to believe that it is an invalid array.

I have tried to create a state name `monster_special_ability` and manually set the array in the following way:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters/${this.state.number}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        this.setState({ monster: responseData })
        this.setState({ monster_special_abilities: responseData.special_abilities })
      })
  }
```

I have tried putting debuggers in the `setState` function, and typing in `responseData.special_abilities` into the console returns the array that I want, but after the state is set, it seems that the array is not usable (it becomes a **proto**:object)

Comment: Be careful when using async data, check if it's already available before trying to use it: `this.state.monster.special_abilities` may not be defined on your first render, but after you fetch it, it is

Comment: @BravoZulu, I did try that by putting in an if statement to check to see if the state is empty. I got the same response in my browser console.

Comment: What's your if statement? Check my answer below, it may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice when using fetch in react component is to use a loading state. Set it to false initially and once fetch is resolved, set it to true. You only render your component if the loading state is true. So your final code should look something like the following:

```js
class MonstersContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isDataLoaded: false,
      monster: {},
      number: Math.floor((Math.random())*325)
    }
    this.handleRandomClick = this.handleRandomClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/monsters/${this.state.number}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        this.setState({ 
          isDataLoaded: true,
          monster: responseData 
        })
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  render() {
    const { isDataLoaded, monster } = this.state;
    const monsterProps = { isDataLoaded, monster };
    return <Monsters {...monsterProps} />
  }
}

function MonsterSpecialAbilities(desc) {
  return <div>desc</div>
}

function Monsters(props) {
   const {isDataLoaded, monster} = props;
   let spec_abilities;
    
    if (isDataLoaded && monster.special_abilities) {
      spec_abilities = monster.special_abilities.map((ab) =>
        <MonsterSpecialAbilities
          desc={ab.desc}
        />
      );    
    }

    return (isDataLoaded && spec_abilities && monster.name) ? (
      <div>
        {monster.name}
        {spec_abilities}
      </div>
    ): <div>loading monster data...</div>;
   
}
```

See it live on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cakireweku/edit?html,js,output).

Note that the fetch might fail and you also need to do something about it. You could add another state called `errorMessage` that displays an error message. In your case, make sure that your host is running on http and NOT https since the fetch url does not work when fetched using https.

Comment: So it's showing the loader, but the isDataLoaded is not executing during the componenetDidMount. The monster state however is changing correctly.

Comment: It didn't go to the catch, same problem; monster is fetched correctly, but `isDataLoaded` is still false

Comment: I have updated my code and put a working version live on js bin: http://jsbin.com/cakireweku/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! I will play around and see if I can refactor the code in any way. Thank you so much for showing me loaders! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change your monster to `null` in your initial state and your render to:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.monster) {
      return <div> Loading monster...</div>;
    }

    const spec_abilities = this.state.monster.special_abilities.map(ab =>
        <MonsterSpecialAbilities desc={ab.desc} />
    )

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.monster.name}
        {spec_abilities}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

If you need your `monster` to be an object you could check if there are already `special_abilities` set, insted of the `monster`